# GIT: how to merge changes, which were earlier removed from the merged commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

I have two branches, develop and master. I wanted to cherry pick some commits regarding one specific feature from develop into master. But the number of commits cherry pick able from dev to master were around 106, that means I had to go through all of them in order to filter out the relevant ones. To avoid having to go through the changes of each commit and then cherry pick individual ones or a range of those, I thought to take the short cut :D. I merged develop into master, there were around 115 file changes in the merge commit.

I went through each file and removed those changes which were not relevant to the feature. In case of some files I removed them altogether and for some I took only partial changes and removed the unnecessary changes. After going through all of the 115, there were around 55 filtered files left which were relevant to the feature which I then commited in the merge commit.

Now when I look at the git log of master, log appears as though all 106 commits were merged into the master and on the top appears my merge commit named 'merged develop into master'.
Now I want to merge develop into master in order to actually merge the remaining files which I removed earlier from the merge commit, git says there is nothing to merge although there are changes among both the branches but due to the fact that I removed those from the merge commit I am unable to move those changes into master now.
Do I need to remove the merge commit from the master or is there any way to force fully merge the differences?
what should be the right method here in order to avoid any future issues?

Comment: You seem to be using the term "commit" and "file" interchangeably, as if they are the same thing.  Do you have 106 _commits_ which are candidates for cherry picking, or are the 106 _files_ which might be added to some branch?

Comment: there were 106 commit cherry pick able among the two branches, and there were 115 file changes in those 106 commits.

Comment: Two clarifications:  first, did you merge `develop` *into* `master` (i.e., on `master`, you ran `git merge develop`, and not the other way around), and second, what does your current working tree look like:  is it clean with the file contents containing only the first feature, or is it dirty with uncommitted changes from the other features?

Comment: And I guess a third clarification:  did this merge just happen, or did you do it a while ago and commit more work on `master` and `develop` before discovering you had a big problem?

Comment: 1. yes i merged develop into master
2. only the required feature is present in the master and no unnecessary feature is there
3. I did add one new commit on master after that, which can be removed if resetting is the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your shortcut misused "merge".  When you try to merge two branches, get conflicts, manually resolve them, and then commit the merge, you are telling Git that the "correct" way of combining these two branches (and **all** the commits made on those two branches) is the way **you** chose to manually resolve the commit.  If you "re-merge" from `develop`, Git won't overrule your manual conflict resolution because you've already told Git what the correct merge is, and it won't try to contradict you (well, unless it gets really confused).  Git can't tell the difference between changes you made that were necessary to resolve the two merges versus changes that you wanted to "save for later".

You *will* have to reset the bad merge, but here's how you can do it relatively automatically and without much fuss.  You mentioned you had one more commit on `master` since the merge.  If that wasn't there at all, you could skip a few steps, but I've given the more general solution below, which would also work if you'd added additional commits on both `master` and `develop`.

I'm assuming the following.

- When you made the "bad merge", you merged `develop` into `master` (i.e., you were on `master` and ran `git merge develop` and not the other way around).
- You don't care too much about how the history looks at this point, you just want to get the "lost" changes from `develop` from before the "bad merge" (plus the additional changes since then, if you had any) successfully merged into `master`.
- You have not published `master` or `develop` anywhere, so no other respositories rely on their histories.
- You currently have `master` checked out in a clean tree.

As with any messy Git manipulation, it's not a bad idea to make a full backup (either `cp -a` or `git clone mirror`) of your repository here.

First, let's name the bad merge.  Find its hash in your log and create a tag for it.  (In your case, it's `master^`, but more generally you might have to search for it.)

```
git tag bad_merge 8354cbeb
git log bad_merge  # !! double check that this points to the bad merge !!
```

Now, we're going to check out a new `fix_merge` branch.  We'll start it at the `bad_merge`:

```
git checkout -b fix_merge bad_merge
```

Then, we'll roll the branch back to the state of `master` just before the "bad merge", but keeping the working directory as-is (so it contains your manual edits to add the first feature to `master`):

```
git reset HEAD^
```

and we'll recommit these manual edits:

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'fix_merge: add first feature to master'
```

Now, we're going to do a somewhat complicated rebase.  (This is the step that would be unnecessary if you didn't have any commits on `master` since the bad merge.)

```
git checkout master
git branch master_backup   # make a copy in case something goes wrong
git rebase --onto fix_merge bad_merge master
```

This transplants changes made on the `master` branch from **after** the bad merge through to its current state (i.e., the part of the tree after `bad_merge` up to `master`) **ONTO** our repaired branch `fix_merge`.  After the rebase, `master` will point to the transplanted branch.  There should be no conflicts, because the trees in `bad_merge` and `fix_merge` match exactly; it's just the commit history that's being rewritten because one has a merge and one doesn't.

We now have the following situation:

- The history of `master`, instead of having a merge from `develop`, now has a single commit for the manual edits you made to add the first feature, plus the additional work you've done on `master` since the bad merge.  What it's missing is the history of having been (badly) merged from `develop`.
- The `develop` branch now has the (complex) history of that first feature, plus the features you developed before the bad merge but wanted to "save for later", plus additional work you've done since (which you don't have in your case, but this solution would work for those, too).

This is more or less where you'd be if you'd cherry picked the first feature from `develop`, except it's all been cherry picked in a single commit instead of multiple commits.  Now, if you merge `develop` into `master`:

```
git checkout master    # probably already there, but make sure
git merge develop
```

and resolve any conflicts -- and there may be quite a few, since Git is trying to match all the individual commits for the first feature in the `develop` branch with the big monolithic commit in `master`, so this is a potentially ugly merge -- then you can commit the merge:

```
git commit
```

and you should finally have `master` successfully merged with all the changes from `develop` both from before and after the bad commit.

At this point, you probably want to consider merging `master` back into `develop` or abandon `develop` entirely and re-branch it from `master`.

Comment: I actually ended by resetting my master, to the situation before the merge, than pushed changes by force, (i don't like pushing by force as every one else also had to git reset --hard to discard the bad merge). And then properly cherry picked commits into master. Then re applied my changes which were on top of the bad merge, and then made any further merges. This actually wasted a lot of time, but I learned my lesson ;)

I do like your solution more, as its more safer in terms of having backups and more sleek, instead of resetting everything :D

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need to do here is add a small change to develop branch (let it be an extra space) then switch to master 
git merge develop will add the changes including the deleted changes you previously deleted 
then git push 
 To avoid future issues is in my opinion each feature should be on a branch and once done will be merged to master

Comment: i guess this solution could only work if I do this in each file or line, which i removed from the merge commit, which is not feasible.