# Git merging another developer's branch into my own branch: his changes are not showing in my branch

Tags: git, version-control

might be best explain with an example.

- 2 branches (let's call them "his-branch" and "my-branch")
- his-branch was merged into our testing branch called "stable". my-branch was never merged into stable. I used bitbucket's merge/pull request feature to do the merge.
- I needed some code from his-branch so I merged stable branch into my-branch.
- his-branch was subsequently removed from stable because it has issues and we need to do a prod release. his-branch was removed from stable by reverting the previous merge/pull request (done using bitbucket's web UI).
- I updated my-branch with the latest changes from stable branch. (so in this case, code changes from his-branch were deleted from my-branch)

**This is my problem**: I tried merging his-branch to my-branch and the changes in his-branch is not showing up. As an example, a constant was added in one of the Java classes in his-branch. This constant is not showing up in my-branch after merging.

No errors showed up when I merged his-branch to my-branch. I used SourceTree and git console command to do the git merge.

How to fix?

Thank you.

Comment: When you merged branch stable into your branch, you already merged his-branch into your branch, too. You cannot merge his-branch into your branch *again* (without tricks). Git just does not do that.

Comment: "his-branch was subsequently removed from stable". Which operations did you perform to remove his-branch changes from stable? A reset? A revert?

Comment: From what you describe, it sounds like his changes were reverted, so now your branch has both his changes and the corresponding reverts from stable-branch. So as @j6t already remarked, there's no merging his changes *again*. But you could revert the reverts (in reverse chronological order).

Comment: You say you need "some code" from his-branch. This sounds like you do not need all their code. Then a better approach is probably to cherry-pick the required commits.

Comment: I think this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52099579/git-how-to-merge-changes-which-were-earlier-removed-from-the-merged-commit

Comment: @dani-vta his-branch was merge to stable using bitbucket's pull/merge request. And then his-branch was removed from stable my reverting the pull/merge request.